# WP behind a Reverse Proxy – 301 redirect in loop - Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to forward/proxy all the traffic from only blog links from my old worpress website that is https://old_wordpress_host.com/blog to new host https://new_wordpress_host.com/

nginx block for proxy on old_wordpress_host.com.conf

```
location ^~ /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_pass https://new_wordpress_host.com/;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
server_name_in_redirect off;
```

}

And then in wordpress wp-config.php on new wordpress new_wordpress_host.com

```
define('.COOKIE_DOMAIN.', 'old_wordpress_host.com');
define('.SITECOOKIEPATH.', '.');

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $list = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $list[0];

        define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://old_wordpress_host.com/blog/');
        define('WP_HOME', 'https://old_wordpress_host.com/blog/');
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'old_wordpress_host.com';
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'https://old_wordpress_host.com';
        $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_ADDR' ] = 'old_wordpress_host.com';

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
                $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite rule in your Nginx configuration is unnecessary since you're handling the path with proxy_pass. remove rewrite rule once and check again

> ```
> location ^~ /blog {
>     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
>     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
>     rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break;
>     proxy_pass https://new_wordpress_host.com;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>     server_name_in_redirect off;
> }
> ```

in wp-config.php you're trying to set the cookie domain and site URL to the old host but it should be the new host

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'new_wordpress_host.com');
define('.SITECOOKIEPATH.', '.');

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $list = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $list[0];

        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'new_wordpress_host.com';
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://new_wordpress_host.com/');
        define('WP_HOME', 'https://new_wordpress_host.com/');
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'https://old_wordpress_host.com';
        $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_ADDR' ] = 'old_wordpress_host.com';

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
                $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
        }
}
```

Comment: My case is the case A on WP Engine reverse proxy. I have implemented according to their document: https://wpengine.com/support/using-a-reverse-proxy-with-wp-engine/ But its not working

Comment: I have updated according to your suggestion and it still going in loop

Comment: you are right the issue is because of rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break; but i need this rule to be able to load blog posts and other assets. how can i do this?

Comment: I have updated the rewrite rule, please check and try